# how to use for loop in a JButton

Tags: java

```
 public void init(GUI gui){
    // the class extends Jframe   
   gui.setSize(1024, 700);
   gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 700));
   gui.setResizable(false);
   gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   gui.setTitle("Student Management System");
   gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl=new JLayeredPane();
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl.setSize(1024,700);
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl.setLayout(null);
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl.setVisible(false);
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl.setOpaque(true);
  // Admin_AllStudents_pnl.setBackground(Color.white);

   String col[]={"ID","Name","Password","Cell","Adress"};
   DefaultTableModel tablemodel=new DefaultTableModel(col,0);
   All_Students=new JTable(tablemodel);


   view_all=new JButton("View_All");
   Admin_AllStudents_pnl.add(view_all);
   view_all.setBorder(null); 
   view_all.setBounds(10,10,view_all.getPreferredSize().width,view_all.getPreferredSize().height);


   view_all.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       @Override
```

// Student and admin are both classes s gets an array list from the admin of all //the students.
//i need to display them in a table format so using for loop.

```
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ArrayList<Student> s=new ArrayList<>();
        s=admin.AllStudent();
        System.out.println("size of s arraylist"+s.size());

       for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
       {
       String Ids=s.get(i).getId();
       String names=s.get(i).getName();
       String passwords=s.get(i).getPass();
       String cells=s.get(i).getCell();
       String adresss=s.get(i).getAdress();
       Object[] data={Ids,names,passwords,cells,adresss};
       tablemodel.addRow(data);
       }
       }

   });

  Admin_AllStudents_pnl.add(All_Students);

   gui.add(Admin_AllStudents_pnl);
```

only the for loop is not working whole code works fine without for loop every variable is already declared the code is about of 1000 lines so i cant upload all of it.

Comment: what is printed out as the size of the arraylist in this line? `System.out.println("size of s arraylist"+s.size());`

Comment: the size of array list is 4 and it prints out right

Comment: the error might not be in for loop i dont know for sure but without the button the code works fine

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  What is the error or problematic behavior you are encountering?  Having this information helps us help you.